# Controlling number of <div> tags shown in foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am building an ecommerce website with asp.net core razor pages and I am currently building the products page. I want the ability to control the number of `<div>` tags shown per line. My current code at the moment just squeezes as much as possible (which i expected) I just don't know how to control it. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Products)
    {
        <div class="col-sm">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </div>    
    }
</div>
```

**Where Model.Products contains a list of 25 products**

Comment: Can you please explain more what you meant by "want the ability to control the number of <div> per line"? I see you're using Bootstrap. Bootstrap4 grid system, i.e., row and col, uses flex-box design. The way you have inside your foreach loop and the css class "col-sm" you use will set each product's width equally alone the line, just like what you said "squeezes as much as possible". If you really meant how to control how many products you want to display per line/row, you have to use media breakpoints to set each product panel's width.

Comment: yes thats what I mean. for example https://www.boohoo.com/mens/shirts shows 5 products. I want to do what as opposed to everything being squeeze into the div rows. Sorry that I am not explaining it properly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you wish to control the number of  tags?

Do you have a maximum number to respect?
If so, you can try taking just the first "DivMaxAmount" amount of items:

```
@{int DivMaxAmount = 25}
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Products.Take(DivMaxAmount))
    {
        <div class="col-sm">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </div>    
    }
</div>
```

This sample will create 25 divs with the first 25 items in the collection, but you can change this number as you wish.

Note if you want consistent ordering you might want to order the collection before taking the items:

```
Model.Products.OrderBy(p => p.PropertyToOrderBy).Take(DivMaxAmount)
```

These methods are available in the [System.Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=netframework-4.7.2) namespace.